# After building a WSUS server in a windows 2016 server I get failed to synchronize error followed by 'System.Net.WebException: The underlying conne...'

Tags: ssl, http, windows-server-2016, wsus

So I started with the basic procedure of adding the Windows Sever Update Services (WSUS) roles.

After doing so I created a self-signed certificate and add the domain names where required.

[Image of left pane that contains the create the cert actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnHhB.png)

[Creating a self signed cert image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7VMp.png)

Then I would configure the HTTP and HTTPS ports respectively and bind the WSUS to my SSL certificate

[Image of Binding WSUS to the certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvhsW.png)

Next, I enforced encryption on WSUS directories under the WSUS administration sites which are 'APIremoting, ClientWebService, DssAuthWebService, ServerSyncWebService, SimpleAuthWebService' by checking the 'Require SSL' check box.

[Image of encryption enforcement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1ceO.png)

After that, I would navigate to 'C:\Program files\Update Services\Tools' folder and write the command that would tell the WSUS to use SSL

[Powershell command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IozI.png)

However now when try to sync it throws an error.

[Update services window showing the error and failure to sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe9DU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a hardware problem how much free space do you have? if that doesnt solve it try to stop and start certificate certificates manualy

Comment: I already tried stopping and starting those manually, i also tried to increase the maximum memory limit